# What's the C++ equivalent to Java's java.io.FileInputStream.read()?

Tags: java, c++, inputstream

How can I turn the following line of Java to C++ code?

```
 FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
 byte[] b = new byte[188];
 int i = 0;
 while ((i = fi.read(b)) > -1)// This is the line that raises my question.
 {
 // Code Block
 }
```

I'm trying to run the following line of code, but it's result is an error.

```
 ifstream InputStream;
 unsigned char *byte = new unsigned char[188];
 while(InputStream.get(byte) > -1)
 {
 // Code Block
 }
```

Comment: [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) ... There's a [read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) method inherited from `std::istream`

Comment: java.io.FileInputStream.read() returns int, ifstream's read() doesn't.

Comment: `std::istream` has `readsome` which returns the number of read bytes

Comment: `std::ifstream::read` returns the `ifstream` object, which can be contextually converted to a `bool` and tested. Like... `while(file.read(byte)){ ...}`. When it fails, you can use [`gcount`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) to check the number of characters that was read before failure

Comment: I've posted the line of code I'm trying to use and that results on errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [`std::ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/), and use either [`get(`)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) to read individual chars one by one, or extraction operator [`>>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) to read any given type that would be in plain text in the input stream, or [`read()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) to read a consecutive number of bytes.

Note that contrary to the java [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read())  the c++ read returns the stream.  If you want to know the number of bytes read, you have to use [`gcount()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/), or alternatively use [`readsome()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/readsome/).

So, possible solution could be:

```
ifstream ifs (f);  // assuming f is a filename
char b[188]; 
int i = 0;
while (ifs.read(b, sizeof(b))) // loop until there's nothing left to read
{
   i = ifs.gcount();   // number of bytes read
   // Code Block
}
```

Comment: I get this error using get():
`error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::char_type {aka char}' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @LucasC.AlvesBittencourt sorry, I thought you wanted to read individual chars.  Please see my edit

Comment: It looks like that solved my problem. Thank you very much.